# Name a reference in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relationships

in my rails app, I have an Organization model, with a reference to a User, which I want to be able to access via organization_instance.adminstrator. I'm not sure how to accomplish this using the belongs_to method.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind. The proper solution (as I found it), is to do the following:

```
belongs_to :administrator, :class_name => "User"
```

interesting what reading the documentation can do for you :D

However, this poses a new question which is not directly apparent from the documentation: How do I generate the migration for this? Would

```
t.references :user
```

or

```
t.references :administrator
```

be the correct way?

Comment: The documentation is confusing on this point. Even if it weren't, tfwright's sarcasm is mean and inappropriate. If tfwright believes a particular section of the docs is relevant, he can post a link. Snide "RTFM" type remarks reinforce stupid hierarchies, discourage novice programmers, and constitute a barrier to access to the core function of this site. If you can't contribute to Stack Overflow constructively, go away.